# Custom Control Client Event

Tags: asp.net

I created one custom datetime control (3 textbox , 1 listbox, 1 image button). Now i want to add new client side event to this custom control. For example , i need to add onchange, onclick ... etc event to this custom c

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here you find all the answers you need:

[Create ASP.NET Server Controls from Scratch](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-asp-net-server-controls-from-scratch/)

[tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_custom_controls.htm)

[ASP.NET Custom Controls: Part 1](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ASPNETCustomControlsPart1.aspx)